# Google photo backup

Tags: lg-g2

I just got a new phone that doesn't have a slot for my old memory card (it has 32gb hd) I backed up the photos on the old phone to google. Now, how can I get them or some of them to my new phone?

Comment: What exactly did you do to back them up?

Comment: If you uploaded them to Google Photos, you should be able to log into your Gmail account and simply open up the Photos app.

Comment: I actually had to delete them all from the Google + site and then upload them all over to get them to the new phone. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The [Google+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus) app provides access to all the photos and albums in your Google+ account.
It also offers you to upload automatically from any photo directory it detects on the device:

> Google+ Photos is a great way to save all your photos, bring the best moments to life, and share with the people that matter. Your photos and videos are stored privately and accessible from anywhere, plus when you turn on Auto Backup they’ll be automatically saved. Relive the moment with photos presented as rich stories, movies, animations, collages, and more. You can find the right photos fast by searching for what’s in the image, even if it’s not in the photo description. And easily add a personal touch with filters and built-in editing tools.